# DataTable serverside processing how disable custome if no data recived

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have used dataTable serverside processing  I want to disable a button if no data received.

```
 var thisTable = $('#examole).DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "info": true,
        "order": [[8, 'desc' ]],
        "dom": '<"top"flip>rt<"bottom"flp>',
        "ajax": {
            url: '/user.php',
            type: 'POST',
        },
```

Below is my button

```
 <select id="btn1">
     <option>Export</option>
     <option id="csv" data>CSV</option>
     <option id="xls" >XLS</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: First count number of rows. if it's == 0, then set button disabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var thisTable = $('#examole').DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "info": true,
            "order": [[8, 'desc' ]],
            "dom": '<"top"flip>rt<"bottom"flp>',
            "ajax": {
                url: '/user.php',
                type: 'POST',

                // add this section
                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    // you may have to deserilize and reserialize data here
                    // depending how your data is handled.
                    if(data.data.length == 0) {
                        $("#btn1").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#btn1").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    return data; 
                }
            },
            // and the rest of your code
```